# How to reinitialize Owl Carousel after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am trying to reinitialize owl carousel after a successful ajax call. The ajax call will change the data but the view should stay the same.I am having an issue where the view carousel structure will not reinitialize. I don't know where I did mistake.

Ajax Request

```
 $(document).on('click', '.category_list', function() {
    var category_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var _token = $('#_token').val();
    var param = 'category_id=' + category_id + '&_token=' + _token;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        url: "/master/sub_category",
        data: param,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#test').html(result);
            var owl = $(".owl-carousel");
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 4,
                navigation: true
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

Controller Function

```
public function getImg() {
    $post_data = Request::all();
    $sub_img = $this->imgModel->getImgList($post_data);
    $sub_img_html = '';
    foreach ($sub_img ['data'] as $data_img ) {
        $img = '/img/sub_category/'.$data_img ['img'];            
        $sub_img_html .= '<div class="item">';
        $sub_img_html .= '<img src="'.$img.'" />';
        $sub_img_html .= '</div>';
    }
    echo $sub_img_html;
}
```

View

```
<div id="demo">
    <div id="test" class="owl-carousel">
        <?php
           if (!empty($img_category)) {
              foreach ($img_category as $imgcategory){
        ?>
        <div class="item">
          <img src='/img/sub_category/<?= imgcategory['subcategory_img'] ?>'/></div>
      <?php
           }
        }
     ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As per your code I make changes please apply this I hope this code work full.

```
success: function(result) {            
            $('#demo').html('<div id="testing" class="owl-carousel"></div>');
            for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                $(".owl-carousel").append('<div class="item"><img src="/img/sub_category/'+result[i].subcategory_img+'" /></div>');
            };
            var owl = $("#testing");
            owl.owlCarousel({
                items: 4,
                navigation: true
            });
```

Answer (score 8):

I believe you will need to destroy and re-initalize the carousel. There is a destroy method you can call;

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L1391

or there is a refresh method;

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L608

or there is an update method;

https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/blob/develop/src/js/owl.carousel.js#L569

I believe these can all be called;

```
$('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel('refresh');
```

Might be worth a try.

Comment: I used `$('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel('refresh');` but still owlCarousel not working.

Comment: I added this way `success: function(result) {
            $('#demo').html(result);
             $('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel('refresh');}` 
is this correct way

Comment: Sorry to clarify, you will need to change 'refresh' to 'destroy' or 'update'. I just meant thats how you call the method.

Comment: `destroy` and `refresh` couple worked well for me, but it reinitialized slider with default options.

Isn't there any way to define options with `$('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel('refresh')`

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me only this worked :

```
$('.owl-gallery').data('owlCarousel').destroy();
$('.owl-gallery').owlCarousel(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my approach and it works with the version 2.2.1 :

```
$.getJSON('testimonials.json', function(data) {

    var content = "";
        for(var i in data["items"]){

             var text = data["items"][i].text;
             var name = data["items"][i].name;
             var position = data["items"][i].position;

             content += text + name + position
        }

        // set the content inside the element
        $("#test_slider").html(content);

        // Now we can call the owlCarousel
        $('#test_slider').owlCarousel({
            dots: false,
            nav: true,
            loop: true,
            margin:30,
            smartSpeed: 700,
            items:1,
            autoplay:true,
        });
});
```

As for testimonials.json looks like this :

```
{
  "items" :
  [
    {
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem Ipsum has been the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.",
      "name": "Maurice Pittmansss",
      "position": "CEO of ABS Ltd.1"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem Ipsum has been the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.",
      "name": "Maurice Pittmanggg",
      "position": "CEO of ABS Ltd.2"
    },
    {
      "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Lorem Ipsum has been the Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing.",
      "name": "Maurice Pittmannnn",
      "position": "CEO of ABS Ltd3."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better

3. Call the plugin
   Now call the Owl initializer function and your carousel is ready.

$(document).ready(function() {

$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();

});

https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Powerful-Customizable-jQuery-Carousel-Slider-OWL-Carousel/#how-to